# Making a parallax background image stay at 100% width when responding

Tags: jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm using this very simple method of Parallax for a background image. 
http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/

It works well only I'd like to tweak it so the image is always full width, no matter what the width of the browser is (rather than cut off the edges and remain full height as you make the browser narrower). I thought I'd be able to do this with CSS alone but I cannot figure it out!

Below is the page I am working on. I have an overlay that is positioned absolutely over the top of the parallax image and 100% width. Both the overlay image and the image behind it are exactly the same dimensions.

http://vurtmedia.co.uk/prev/overlay/

I'd like the overlay to always cover the image behind it exactly. I think by viewing my link it's quite obvious what I am trying to achieve, I'm just not sure it's even possible with this parallax technique. As the images are the same size if they resized in the same way this would work. I can achieve this easily with just two images and no parallax effect like in this version

http://vurtmedia.co.uk/prev/overlay/index2.html

You can see the overlay image covers the one underneath perfectly. Of course I could just use one image for this if I wasn't going for a parallax effect, it's just something I'd really like to get working.

Is there a way to do this, or does anyone have any suggestions of a better way? Even doing it vice versa could work - making the overlay fill full height instead of width...

Comment: _I'd like to tweak it so the image is always full width, no matter what the width of the browser is_ -->  CSS : `img { width : 100% }` ? I guess you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried `width:100% !important` on it but the height is being set in javascript to be the height of the document as far as I can see, so it makes no difference

Comment: Well, just release the height and leave it in auto. Set the width to 100%, the height will adjust automatically

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Setting the image to auto makes in not show up at all. It's something that the jQuery is doing but I can't figure out where to amend or override!

Comment: I've added another link so you can see what I am trying to achieve visually, but I just want to get an added parallax effect on it which is why I've used 2 images   http://vurtmedia.co.uk/prev/overlay/index2.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have modified on [the page you provided](http://vurtmedia.co.uk/prev/overlay/index2.html)  (it's hard to post code in comments)

```
#vurtOverlay{
 position:relative;
 z-index:2;
}

#vurtUnderlay{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 0;
}

section{
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

And now it makes a nice parallax effect when I scroll. The background image is always 100% wide, whatever the browser's width. I hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. It doesn't work for me though! I must be doing something wrong. I've added those modifications so I now have this:
`#vurtOverlay{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

#vurtUnderlay{
 width:100%;
 position: fixed;
   z-index: 0;
   top: 0;
}

section{
 padding:50px;
 position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}`

Comment: Anyway, you're using a plugin (parallax.js). Its sole purpose is making parallaxes. I suggest you to go through its documentation, get started etc. and you'll get your parallax soon.